# Replace specified occurence of string in TextFile.txt

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a program that essentially logs information about a person to a text file (cumulative) each time that it is run.  The user is prompted to enter a first name, last name, favorite color, relationship status (single / dating) among other information. There is also a ticket number assigned which is automated and sequential (*ticketNumber++* after each time it is printed).

The output file (lets call it *outputLog.txt*) looks something to this accord:

```
Time In:  12:57 PM  ( Apr 30, 2015 ) 
Name:  John Doe
Ticket:  31393
Color:  Green
Relationship Status:  single

Time In:  1:58 PM  ( Apr 30, 2015 )
Name:  Jane Doe
Ticket: 31394
Color:  Yellow
Relationship Status:  married
```

What I want to be able to do, when prompted with a ticket number, is find that person and change the relationship status in *someFile.txt*.

What I have been able to do thus far is use a fairly simple "if-statement" to look through the file.  IF the number is found then replace with the new relationship status, ELSE return an error message.  Here is a chunk of the code:

```
//  First a ticket number is stored in --> unsigned int ticketCalled

requestTicket = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ticketCalled];  // (int --> string) 

NSError *error;
NSString *intFilePath = @"/filepath.txt";

NSString *someTicket = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:intFilePath
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                          error:&error];

if (!requestTicket) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSString *replacedString = [someTicket stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:requestTicket
                                                                     withString:@"divorced"];
    [replacedString writeToFile:intFilePath
                     atomically:YES
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                          error:&error];
    NSLog(@"\r Relationship status successfully changed!");
}
```

Obviously this does not do exactly what I want.  What the above code does is replace the ticket number specified with the new relationship status.  What I want to do is located the object (*block of output text*) within the text file using the associated ticket number and then located the relationship status and change the appended text for it.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: what you are saying is to look for the ticket number in the text file. am i correct?

Comment: Yes sir, the number in the text file.  And then go down two lines and replace the string.  (I will edit question to make that clear.  My bad.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to find the ticket number by this:

```
NSRange isRange = [someTicket rangeOfString:@"31393 "     options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(isRange.location == 0) {
  //found it...
       [self changeStatus];
 } else {
NSRange isSpacedRange = [someString rangeOfString:@" 31393 " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(isSpacedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
  //found it...
  [self changeStatus];
  }
}
```

Here is the method to change the status:

```
-(void)changeStatus{

NSString *newString = [someTicket stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"single" withString:@"married"];

}
```

Comment: Finding the ticket number has not been a problem.  The issue is that the ticket number is being replaced by a new string.  I cannot figure out how to do the following once i locate the ticket number: Locate the line which sits 2 below ticket number --> search for string --> replace string.